# Detect when user is holding down on a particular div while moving finger

Tags: jquery

A div of mine (teamheading) can be scrolled directly by the user. It can also be scrolled as a result of moving the grid below it.

When the user taps and holds (this is a question relating to use on mobile) on the teamheading div and moves it back and forth, I want the grid to scroll with it.

I've got this so far.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.teamheading').on('scroll', function() {

    //get left scroll position of team heading
    var teamheading = $(this).scrollLeft();

    //get left scroll position of teamtimematrix
    var teamtimematrix = $('.teamtimematrix').scrollLeft();

    // check if mouse is clicked down on teamheading
    var mouse_is_clicked_down_on_teamheading = ? ? ? ?

      //if mouse is clicked down and holding on teamheading
      if (mouse_is_clicked_down_on_teamheading == true) {

        //if the scroll positions aren't the same, move teamtimematrix to match
        if (teamheading != teamtimematrix) {

          $(".teamtimematrix").scrollLeft(teamheading);

        }

      }

  });

});
```

Unfortunately, I don't know how to detect whether or not the user is currently holding down on the teamheading div.